# Direct Comparison Test verification of understanding

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was given the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4+e^n}$$

And was given instructions to use the Direct Comparison Test to determine if the series converges.

I broke it down into $a_n$ and $b_n$.
$$a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4+e^n}$$
$$b_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^n}$$

Since, $$b_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^n}$$ converges, and $$0 \le a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4+e^n} \le b_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^n}$$ then, 
$$a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4+e^n}$$
converges via Direct Comparison Test.

I am having trouble trying to determine if I am correct with choosing $b_n$ to be: $$b_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{e^n}$$

I am justifying using $b_n$ with this:
$n^4 \lt e^n, n\in(\approx1.43,\infty)$

Comment: All you need to check is whether $$\frac1{n^4+e^n}\le\frac1{e^n}$$.

Comment: I guess my question is:

Should I use $\frac{1}{e^n}$ or $\frac{1}{n^4}$

Comment: They both converge: one much faster than the other!

Comment: @Doxxy -- Either one will work, but $\frac{1}{e^n}$ is more elementary since it only needs the condition for geometric series convergence, whereas $\frac{1}{n^4}$ needs knowledge of the $p$-series convergence criterion.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but wasn't sure. Thank you @Lord

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense @quasi. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you may choose either.  You have both inequalities

$$ 0 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4 + e^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^n} = C_1$$ \

$$ 0 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4 + e^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = C_2$$